# Increasing the rank of null space matrix by real columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

I have a complex matrix $X$ whose size $m$ x $n$ where $m<n$  (for example, $m = 2$ and $n = 6$), I need to get the invertible real matrix $Y$ whose size $n$ x $n$ representing the null space of the imaginary part of matrix $X$. That means that $X\times Y$ is real matrix.

I think the first step of the solution is to get the null space matrix $Y_1$ for the imaginary part of $X$. However, by definition, the rank of the null-space matrix $Y_1$ is less than $n$, in my case, it's $5$. So, does it exist a real column $v$ such that $Y = [Y_1\ \ \ v ]$ is a real and invertible matrix? ($v$ can be a column or a matrix following the size of $Y$ which must be $n$ x $n$).

Comment: please edit your question and make it clear. You wrote that $Y$ is $n\times n$ matrix, so $X_2$ will be $n\times (n+1)$ matrix, so how $X_2$ might be invertible if it is not a square matrix? $X_2$ itself is not well defined

Comment: @Lee sorry for that error, I will correct it right now

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, but maybe this might help you

Any complex matrix $X$ can be partitioned to its real and imaginary part as the following:

$$X=\frac{X+X^*}{2}+\frac{X-X^*}{2},$$

where $\frac{X+X^*}{2}$ is real and $\frac{X-X^*}{2}$ is complex.

So you need to find invertible real $Y$ such that

$$\Big(X-X^*\Big)Y=0.$$

Lets say that $X-X^*=[i\quad 2i]$ and $Y=\begin{bmatrix} 
y_{11} & y_{12}\\ 
 y_{21}&y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$, then we will get:

$$y_{11}+2y_{21}=0 \qquad\Longrightarrow \qquad y_{11}=-2y_{21}$$
$$y_{12}+2y_{22}=0 \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad y_{12}=-2y_{22}$$

then $\det(y_{11}y_{22}-y_{12}y_{21})=\det(-2y_{21}y_{22}+2y_{22}y_{21})=0$, thus $Y$ is not invertible. So I guess you cannot find $Y$, at least not for general $n$.

EDIT: Let $Z=\Im(X)$, then for your case, $\mathrm{dim}[\mathrm{null}(Z)]=5$, which means you cannot construct invertible $6\times 6$ matrix $Y$, such that $ZY=0$, but you can construct $6\times 5$ matrix $Y_1$, such that $ZY_1=0$ or singular $6\times 6$ matrix $Y$, such that $ZY=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think we can get $Y = [Y_1 \  \  \ v]$ where $Y_1$ is the null space matrix of $X$ with removing, for example, the last column and $v$ is a part of the null-space matrix of the whole $X$. In that case $Y$ will be invertible but the raised problem in that case is that $v$ will be complex instead of real! so I am looking for another way to get solve that issue if possible.

Comment: if last column of $Y$ is not a null space of $X$, then how do you achieve $XY=0$? $XY=X[Y_1 \quad v]=[XY_1\quad Xv]$, clearly, $Xv\neq 0$

Comment: I am looking for the matrix $Y$ such that  $Imag(XY) = 0$, not all the resulted matrix $XY = 0$.   On that hand,    Yes you are right if the last column of $Y$ is not null space, so $Imag(XY)$ is not $0$, I am just wondering